# MPEG-DASH mp4 video with EME

Tags: javascript, mpeg-dash

i have an html page that plays a MPEG-DASH segmentated mp4 file.
I've generated "segmentated chunk" using MP4Box tool to a .mp4 file.

My html source is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
          <title>Dash.js Rocks</title>
          <style>
             video {
             width: 640px;
             height: 360px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <video id="videoPlayer" controls></video>
    </div>
    <script src="http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/pubblicita_audio_video/video.mpd";
            var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
            player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
```

Well, this works fine.
Now, i would get EME feature to this code.
How could i

1) generate an entrypted file from .mp4?

2) decrypt that file and playout itself from dash.js (as the my html page)?

Sorry for my english!

Thanks

Comment: @CyberJacob So far i've tried to playing out a video locating in my webserver tomcat with dash.js. This video has been segmentated and played-out with dash.js, using mpd. I've readed about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094099/integrating-html5-eme-video-with-edx-platform-why-is-initdatatype-empty   and this https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/ but i don't know how to use EME or Common EME with dash.js. Thanks for the support

Comment: @CyberJacob My video isn't encrypted with MP4Box -crypt, but only segmentated

Comment: for now i haven't solved that problem. I need help, please